# Sleeping with pipes in Haste and Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes, haste

I'm working on a Haskell program that makes heavy use of the Pipes library.  I'm porting part of the library to [Haste](http://haste-lang.org/).  The one place where I've hit a stumbling block is in the odd way that javascript handles sleeping.

What I wanted to write was a simple pipe that delays before sending its results

```
sleeper :: Int -> Pipe a a IO ()
sleeper time = forever $ do
                   temp <- await
                   sleep time
                   yield temp
```

However, it seems that the sleeping works like a callback.

```
setTimeout :: MonadIO m => Int -> IO () -> m ()
```

I tried doing

```
sleeper time = do
                   temp <- await
                   yield temp
                   setTimeout time $ sleeper time
```

But the types don't line up properly.  Is there a way to get a delaying pipe?

Comment: You could emulate sleeping by waiting on an mvar which gets populated in another thread via the callback.

Comment: Do you _really_ want to sleep in a JavaScript environment? I'm not familiar with Haste, but if it doesn't use a WebWorker, you would freeze up your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at https://github.com/imalsogreg/pipes-rt/blob/master/lib/Pipes/RealTime.hs#L127
There is a function pauseUntil there